# Pointing to the base object from the variable object

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a transformation class

```
  class Transformation
  {

       private:
        Sum_Position pos;

       public:
           Transformation();
           Transformation(Sum_Position pos);
           Transformation(const Transformation& transformation);

           Sum_Position* GetPosition();
           void SetPosition(Sum_Position pos);
           int GetContainer( Container *cont);

   };
```

which is data type in Container class

```
     class Container
     { 
          private:
          std::string stdstrContainerName;
          std::string stdstrPluginType;
          Geometry* Geom;
          Sum_Material Material;
          Transformation transformation;   // datatype
          std::string stdstrImagePath;
          Texture2D texture;


   // Public Function here

       };
```

Is it possible for me to return a pointer pointing to the container object from the Transformation class object

```
    int Transformation::GetContainer( Container *cont);
```

Comment: Not unless `Transformation` stores a pointer to the owning container. Also, the signature of `GetContainer` function makes little sense - is it expected to copy a `Container` instance into `*cont`?

Comment: hi igor how can i do that.

Comment: How can you do what? Have a member of type `Container*` in `Transformation`? The same way you add a member of any other type.

Comment: int is being used a bool variable and i can send a container varible as reference to the function.

Comment: Why have you not written *GetContainer* like you wrote *GetPosition*. Instead of writing ``Container * GetContainer()`` you wrote ``int GetContainer(Container *)`` The intention of your code is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic here. When you construct the Transformation instance you have to pass in a pointer to the container. Stripping out the code irrelevant to the issue at hand you could do.

```
// Forward declare
class Container;

class Transformation
{

private:
    Container * _parent;
public:
    Transformation(Container * parent):
        _parent(parent)
    {}

    Container* GetContainer(){
        return _parent;
    }

};


class Container
{ 
private:
  Transformation _transformation;  

public:
  // Construct _transformation with a pointer to the container
  Container():
     _transformation(this)
  {}
};
```